# Can you export a Queue from Dynamics CRM?

Tags: export, queue, dynamics-crm

Can you export a Queue from Dynamics CRM?

I have a number of workflows that assign certain tasks to Queues for users to pick up later.  There doesn't seem to be a way to export a Queue from CRM with the other customisations which means all the queues have to be setup again after a deployment.  Am I just missing where to export Queues as I don't really want to write database scripts?

Kind regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no supported way, that I'm aware of, to migrate Queues.  Unfortunately you'll need to set them up in your new environment.  Also, all workflows that make reference to these queues will break when you migrate customizations.

Comment: Thanks for that, it's what I thought, but just wanted to check.  Hopefully it'll be there in CRM 5.0.

Answer (score 0):

If you are importing a teams in DCRM, it will automatically create a default queue for that team.

So if you are also planning to queue which usually happens, while working with queues.

Go just import teams and you will see autiomatically one default queue is created for that team.

In your import teams.csv leave the column blank for default queues.

Comment: I am just suggesting another way,
Its not for OP's only, it's for whole community.